# Pierdo el diccionario de Session al intentar generar un pdf con rotativa

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

Estoy utilizando el diccionario de sesión para manejar la sesión de usuario, y también información relativa a la empresa, desde la vista llamo al Action ImprimirReporte y cuando se hace el return entonces me salta una excepción de referencia a un objeto nulo, el cual es oEmpresa, en el Action VerFactura. Cabe aclarar que uso el diccionario de sesión en otros controladores y vistas y siempre funciona bien. Es por eso que creo que el problema está relacionado con el uso de Rotativa. ¿Que puede estar provocando la pérdida del diccionario de session o es otro el problema?. Estoy usando .net Framework, NO es .net core.

```
    public ActionResult VerFactura(string NumFactura)
    {
        try
        {
            Empresa oEmpresa = (Empresa)HttpContext.Session["Empresa"];
            int idEmpresa = oEmpresa.IdEmpresa;

            using (InventarioTNRDEntities db = new InventarioTNRDEntities())
            {
                var existeFactura = from _empresa in db.Empresa
                                    join _ctgMasterFactura in db.CatalogoFacturas
                                    on _empresa.IdEmpresa equals _ctgMasterFactura.IdEmpresa
                                    where _ctgMasterFactura.IdEmpresa == idEmpresa
                                    join _masterFacturas in db.MasterFacturas
                                    on _ctgMasterFactura.IdCatalogoFacturas equals _masterFacturas.IdCatalogoFacturas
                                    where _masterFacturas.IdCatalogoFacturasMasterFactura == _ctgMasterFactura.IdCatalogoFacturas + "-" + NumFactura
                                    select _masterFacturas;

                if(existeFactura.Count() != 1)
                {
                    TempData["NotificacionIndex"] = "2";
                    TempData["NotificacionMensaje"] = "No se ha encontrado la factura.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
                }
                else
                {
                    AllListViewModels allListViewModels = new AllListViewModels();

                    allListViewModels.listaDeMasterFacturasList = (from _empresa in db.Empresa
                                                                    join _ctgMasterFactura in db.CatalogoFacturas
                                                                    on _empresa.IdEmpresa equals _ctgMasterFactura.IdEmpresa
                                                                    where _ctgMasterFactura.IdEmpresa == idEmpresa
                                                                    join _masterFacturas in db.MasterFacturas
                                                                    on _ctgMasterFactura.IdCatalogoFacturas equals _masterFacturas.IdCatalogoFacturas
                                                                    where _masterFacturas.IdCatalogoFacturasMasterFactura == _ctgMasterFactura.IdCatalogoFacturas + "-" + NumFactura
                                                                    select new ListaDeMasterFacturasListViewModel
                                                                    {
                                                                        IdCatalogoFacturasMasterFactura = _masterFacturas.IdCatalogoFacturasMasterFactura,
                                                                        FechaVenta = _masterFacturas.FechaVenta,
                                                                        FormaPago = _masterFacturas.FormaPago,
                                                                        NombreApellidoCliente = _masterFacturas.NombreApellidoCliente,
                                                                        NombreVendedor = _masterFacturas.NombreVendedor,
                                                                        CreditoMeses = _masterFacturas.CreditoMeses,
                                                                        Observaciones = _masterFacturas.Observaciones,
                                                                        ValorTotal = _masterFacturas.ValorTotal,
                                                                        DescuentoTotal = _masterFacturas.DescuentoTotal,
                                                                        SubTotal = _masterFacturas.SubTotal,
                                                                        IvaTotal = _masterFacturas.IvaTotal,
                                                                        RetencionTotal = _masterFacturas.RetencionTotal,
                                                                        TotalFinal = _masterFacturas.TotalFinal,
                                                                        Anulada = _masterFacturas.Anulada
                                                                    }).ToList();

                    allListViewModels.listaDetallesFacturaList = (from _empresa in db.Empresa
                                                                    join _ctgMasterFactura in db.CatalogoFacturas
                                                                    on _empresa.IdEmpresa equals _ctgMasterFactura.IdEmpresa
                                                                    where _ctgMasterFactura.IdEmpresa == idEmpresa
                                                                    join _masterFacturas in db.MasterFacturas
                                                                    on _ctgMasterFactura.IdCatalogoFacturas equals _masterFacturas.IdCatalogoFacturas
                                                                    join _detalleFactura in db.DetalleFactura
                                                                    on _masterFacturas.IdCatalogoFacturasMasterFactura equals _detalleFactura.IdCatalogoFacturasMasterFactura
                                                                    where _detalleFactura.IdCatalogoFacturasMasterFactura == _ctgMasterFactura.IdCatalogoFacturas + "-" + NumFactura
                                                                    select new ListaDetallesFacturaListViewModel
                                                                    {
                                                                        IdCatCdgLinSubProd = _detalleFactura.IdCatalogoCodLineaCodSubCodProd,
                                                                        CantidadProducto = _detalleFactura.CantidadProducto,
                                                                        PrecioVenta = _detalleFactura.PrecioUnitarioVenta,
                                                                        DescuentoDetalle = _detalleFactura.Descuento,
                                                                        IvaDetalle = _detalleFactura.Iva,
                                                                        SubtotalDetalle = _detalleFactura.SubtotalDetalle,
                                                                        TotalDetalle = _detalleFactura.TotalDetalle
                                                                    }).ToList();

                    return View(allListViewModels);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["NotificacionIndex"] = "3";
            TempData["NotificacionMensaje"] = "Ha ocurrido un error desconocido en el servidor. " + ex.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
        }
    }

    //Impresiones
    public ActionResult ImprimirReporte(int Sentinela, string NumReporte)
    {
        if (Sentinela == 0)
        {
            return new ActionAsPdf("VerFactura", new { NumFactura = NumReporte })
            {
                FileName = "Test.pdf"
            };
        }
        TempData["NotificacionIndex"] = "2";
        TempData["NotificacionMensaje"] = "No se recibió un numero de reporte a generar.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
    }
```

y este es el código desde la vista

```
    function VerFactura() {
    var esteInput = document.getElementById('numeroFactura').value;
    if (esteInput != '' && esteInput.length > 0) {
        var url = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ImprimirReporte", "Reportes", new { Sentinela = 1, NumReporte = "valor" , _numEmpresa = oEmpresa.IdEmpresa}))";
        console.log(url);
        url = url.replace("valor", esteInput);
        console.log(url);
        location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, si lo he entendido bien oEmpresa ==null  y te salta la excepcion en `int idEmpresa=oEmpresa.IdEmpresa;`  ya que es el unico en el que usas el objeto  me equivoco?

Comment: En caso de ser así mirar qué tipo de objeto devuelve `HttpContext.Session["Empresa"]` lo puedes hacer con debug o imprimiendo `typeof(HttpContext.Session["Empresa"])` si coincide con la classe que datos contiene

Comment: @rexxarcat si, en esa línea se produce la excepción. Con respecto al segundo comentario, si intento hacer el typeof, me da un error de 'el tipo Session no existe en el tipo HttpContext'.

Comment: He optado por enviar el dato que se hace null de otra forma, lo obtengo en razor y lo envío como parametro al ActionResult, quedando así public ActionResult ImprimirReporte(int Sentinela, string NumReporte, int _numEmpresa) y el otro ActionResult queda así public ActionResult VerFactura(string NumFactura, int idEmpresa). No es una respuesta a mi pregunta pero lo pongo aquí por si sirviera de algo. Además he agregado a la publicación la función donde genero la url para llamar al action.